# Css,Js how to convert a number to the animaition time

Tags: javascript, css, variables, time, css-animations

At first, I try to use

```
--Time: 0.1s;
animation-delay:--Time;
```

But this don't work, it only work when

```
animation-delay:0.1s;
```

Why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please, write more code, so that we understand what you wanna say?

Comment: ...and read how to use custom properties with css

Comment: It’s a simple typo. To use a custom property you need to use `animation-duration: var(--Time)`

Answer (score 1):

A common best practice is to define custom properties on the `:root` pseudo-class, so that it can be applied globally across your HTML document:

```
:root {
  --Time: 0.1s;
}
```

Then use it with `var(...)`

```
element {
  animation-delay: var(--Time);
}
```